# EF Code First 6 With "Multiple" many to many self referencing

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, self-referencing-table

I have one entity like this:

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Prerequisites { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Equivalents { get; set; }

    public Course()
    {
        Prerequisites = new HashSet<Course>();
        Equivalents = new HashSet<Course>();
    }
}
```

I want to create to different table for "Prerequisites" and "Equivalents".
How can i configure it?

Comment: Then why are you making them as the same type of the Course? If you want them in different table i think you've got a design problem then.

Comment: Thanks for reply. can you write your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This could help

```
public class Course
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("PrerequisiteFor")]
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Prerequisites { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("EquivalentTo")]
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Equivalents { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Equivalents")]
    public virtual ICollection<Course> EquivalentTo { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Prerequisites")]
    public virtual ICollection<Course> PrerequisiteFor { get; set; }

    public Course()
    {
        Prerequisites = new HashSet<Course>();
        Equivalents = new HashSet<Course>();
        PrerequisiteFor = new HashSet<Course>();
        EquivalentTo = new HashSet<Course>();

    }
}
```